Installing the default Gazebo/ROS pairing
It is commonly recommended that the fortress version of Gazebo is the best fit for ROS Humble.
However, the command sudo apt-get install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-ros-gz might install version 11 instead, as it aligns with the default ROS repository for your distribution.
There shouldn't be any major issues using version 11, but if you specifically need fortress, you may need to install it manually for compatibility.

But what's the question?

It was mentioned.

ROS 2 Humble is paired with Gazebo Ignition by default:
https://gazebosim.org/docs/latest/ros_installation/#installing-the-default-gazebo-ros-pairing
Gazebo Ionic is set as version 9: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/f0cde0574b357fba3cb9ee3f22df0108bda44db1/CMakeLists.txt#L6
Ionic will not run on Ubuntu 2, which is the recommended version for Ubuntu 22.
You might mean Gazebo Classic if you are talking about version 11.

Why does the command sudo apt-get install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-ros-gz install Gazebo 11, when it is stated that Humble has the best compatibility with Fortress?

I'm not sure that's true. Which Ubuntu version are you on?

The ros-humble-ros-gz package was upgraded to version 0.244.16-2jammy.20241205.212526. The installed version of Gazebo on your system is 11.10.2.
